# instagram api delete comment endpoint

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to delete comment on Instagram with api but I got error. I dont want to post a comment only delete. So, Do I need to fill this form:

https://help.instagram.com/contact/185819881608116

Also, app is still under development in fact there is no app right now. How can I fill this form do you have experience about that? If they dont give me authorization then I dont want to start development anyway.

Please any suggestions. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried something? We can't to all work!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to be authorized to delete a comment.
You probably get error following reasons;

- Your app user didn't give *comments* permission
- You try to delete a comment which you can't
- You try to delete comment by http post or http get in your api call. you must use http delete method